# Which Apache Camel method converts Java Object to XML?

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-ftp

How to Marshal back bean body to XML

```
.bean("contentEnrichService", "getDataFromBubla")
.unmarshal(new JaxbDataFormat(JAXBContext.newInstance(EmploymentUpdateRequest.class)))
.bean("contentEnrichService", "updateEmployeeData")
.marshal(new JaxbDataFormat(JAXBContext.newInstance(EmploymentUpdateRequest.class))) // <--------- HOW
```

In "getDataFromBubla"; I have loaded some data from Database.

Then i unmarshal incoming XML and supply to "updateEmployeeData" in which i have update the EmployeeUpdateRequest to data from Database.

Now i want to convert this back to XML

Which Apache Camel Method will do the same and particularly Body of exchange which contains now updated object?

Comment: what do you meant by which method? doesn't this line work for you? `.marshal(new JaxbDataFormat(JAXBContext.newInstance(EmploymentUpdateRequest.class)))`  if not what error are you getting?

Comment: your question is unclear, maybe you are asking 'How Apache Camel work to converts Java Object to XML'?